# Struggling with slideToggle on nested lists

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, nested-class

first, to be honest I'm a noob when it comes to Jquery. I've been watching a ton of tutorials and reading on the jquery site itself. While I am beginning to understand it, the concept hasn't "clicked" for me as of yet.

I'm currently working on a product display to where I want a box to slide down when hovering over the product image. This box contains a list of the models.

I've got the page set up here:

http://www.tailwatersflyfishing.com/sage-fly-rods

This is the effect I'm trying to duplicate (one of our rod vendors)

http://www.sageflyfish.com/rods-landing.html

I've attempted writing the code, but have failed at getting it to work. This is what I currently have in the page:

```
$('document').ready(function () {
    $('.rod-tall').children('.rod-inner').children('.rod-list').hide();
    $('.rod-list ul div li ul li a').click(function() {
        window.location = $(this).attr('href');
    });

    $(".rod-tall .rod-inner").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).children('.rodlist').children('.desc-box').slideToggle('fast');
    });

    $(".rod-tall .rod-inner").mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).children('.rodlist').children('.desc-box').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```

----UPDATE----

I now have this included in my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.rod-list').hide();
   $('.rod-tall').hover(function() {
   $('.rod-list',this).slideToggle('fast');
   },function() {
   $('.rod-list',this).slideToggle('fast');
  });​
</script>
```

All prototype errors are gone. BUT I am getting this error (**Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL**) which I hope is the cause of this  script not working. Is there an invalid character or invisible character that causes this error?

Thanks!

Comment: No quotes around document in `$('document').ready(`.

Comment: Ok - I'm seeing progress. At least I've got a few of the boxes hiding. Here is a live version: http://jsfiddle.net/mattj06/TgFvP/14/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this (**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/TgFvP/15/)**):

**jQuery**:

```
$('.rod-list').hide();
$('.rod-tall').hover(function() {
    $('.rod-list',this).slideToggle('fast');
},function() {
    $('.rod-list',this).slideToggle('fast');
});
```

**CSS**:

```
.rod-list {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks! So I guess I don't need $('document').ready();? Also, I've implemented this into the site and I'm not seeing any effects taking place. jQuery library is included so I'm not sure why it's not working on the site. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you should probably keep the document.ready part as that just runs the code when the DOM has loaded. The code above (and in the fiddle) is meant to exist with the document.ready call.

Comment: As for why it's not working on your site, when I load your page and open Firebug I'm seeing several errors, most prototype related.

Comment: Ok - I'll try and get it resolved. Thanks a million for taking the tim e to help. Very much appreciated.

Comment: No problem. If you feel that this answered your question, consider upvoting it or marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Should I consider using $noConflict() ?

Comment: If you think the errors on the page are due to conflicting libraries then that may help. I didn't get a chance to examine the full code of your page but it's a starting point.

Comment: It didn't work (or I coded incorrectly). I'll get in touch with the guy that originally built our site and see what he thinks.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on the page:

```
window.location = $(this).attr('href';)
```

The semi-colon is inside of the parens.

Comment: Ok I just fixed that and I'm still not seeing any change. Does my code even look remotely correct?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.rod-list').hide();

    $('.rod-tall').on({
        mouseenter: function() {
            $('.rod-list', this).slideDown('fast');
        },
        mouseleave: function() {
            $('.rod-list', this).slideUp('fast');    
        }
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TgFvP/16/)

Comment: Thanks adeneo - this works great but I did want the images to stick in place. The above example with absolute positioning did the trick. Thanks!